# Highcharts problems: variable legend height

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have to set the height & width of the Highcharts placeholder. But the data to be displayed is variable. When the series names(long name) come to much more. The lengend height grows too high and hide the chart.

How could I solve this problem? Hoping to get some help.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: is there any clean solution jet? I've tried this with the marginBottom, but it seems a bit hacky...

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue as you have mentioned. I was setting chart height and marginBottom property for the chart. I removed the marginBotton property and its working fine. AS your legend grows, the chart canvas area gets adjusted by itself and the legend does not overlap with the plot area

Comment: Not sure if it's util, but also there is a propetry called spacingBottom.

Answer (score 1):

After your chart loads.. put this in your code..

```
$('.highcharts-legend').attr('transform', 'translate(50,400)')
```

But It will still move if you resize the browser...

Ill let you know if I figure it out..

Answer (score 1):

As you can see **[here](http://www.highcharts.com/component/content/article/2-news/45-highcharts-introduces-legend-paging)** the release 2.2.4 introduces legend paging.
You can custom it following the [reference](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/ref/#legend-navigation).

Answer (score 0):

As you add your series to the chart just stop adding them to the legend after a certain point (eg after 5) with the following option:

```
showInLegend: false
```

docs: http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#plotOptions-series

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7Mmee/14/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I need the legend. I'm trying to find another solution. :)

Comment: Then you probably need to make your chart height much bigger to fit everything. You can do this by setting the height with css on the element the chart will render to.

Comment: There is a problem that sometimes there are few items to show, so the margin will be too large. I'm still trying to get some solution.

Answer (score 0):

see this jfiddle link.[this is fiddle and highchart links](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#legend--width)

http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/B9L2b/

I think this will solve your problem.